# Show id or name attribute in the dom element which is created by React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am using react native web and on integrating with a 3rd party tool I found out that the tool require either **Id** attribute or **Name** attribute to function. Is there a way to achieve the following?

For example:
In React Native

```
<TextInput id="text-input" ... > ... </TextInput>
```

Expected output in Browser

```
<input id='text-input' ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out in order to maintain compatibility with ReactNative, RNW uses `nativeID` This is in the docs [here](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/storybook/?selectedKind=Components&selectedStory=View&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0)

So to set an ID on a view in react native web, which will be mapped to the elements dom node do this

```
<View nativeID="some-id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through React Native documentation I found a way to achieve this. React Native allows component manipulation by using `setNativeProps`.

The documentation for this can be found [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation).